# propper feature encoding

Tags: dataset, feature-engineering, feature-extraction, features, feature-construction

I working with the following data set
[image]
also here is it's detailed description of "packet_dat" column

[image]

I can't understand how I can encode packet_dat column into proper feature so my classification model would work